# load VBA data to line chart

Tags: excel, vba

I need to feed data into a line chart with VBA. I need to give a basic unidimensional range when I do it with Excel in a raw test. The thing is that now I need to hide some things in VBA code, so that the user just sees a curve resulting of some basic input at the click of a button.

I think there are at least two options for me :

1. either have the chart object placed in the Excel before, and having it point to some VBA snippet. In this case, should I somehow point to VBA from Excel ? Or would VBA access the chart area by some ID ?
   [image: chart select data]
2. create everything dynamically from VBA, the chart window, the chart, and the series input. This might be trickier to figure out maybe as I have frozen panes, so there would be the question of which pane is active (I'd like to avoid to have to do Selects to select the right one)

What would you recommend ? And in either case, how to actually do it ? What type of data to put in ?

Thank you so much !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was involved in a project a couple of years ago that might be relevant.

A report was created monthly for the organisation's management board which contained dozens of charts.  It was a near full time job for a statistician to collate and process data from across the organisation that provided the source data for these charts.  I was asked to automate what could be automated.

It became clear that the appearance of the chart could not be automated.  The statistician and the management board's staff held regular discussions and often agreed minor changes which they thought would better present the organisation's performance.

I could automate the collection of the data, its processing and placing of the results in the ranges from which the charts got their data.  The most I ever did with a chart was change the size of a source range.

What would be the parameters that would control your macro's changes to a chart?  How would your macro get the determine: type of chart, nature of the axes, text, etc?

Hope these thoughts help.  I could look out my notes if my experience seems particularly relevant.

Comment: I'm plotting a distribution, the range is about 39000 lines, I want to hide it all in VBA. Getting the data from a range on the sheet and just update the range from VBA would be easy but it is not applicable.

Comment: My uses don't care about the axis names and stuff like that, the focus is just the curve, even no metadata would be fine.

Comment: I am not sure I understand. I thought the source data for a chart had to be a range of cells. How can you hide the source data in VBA? An approach that I have just tested is to have the chart in A.xls and the data in B.xls. I set A.xls to not update links (Edit -> Links -> Startup prompt). The result is that the chart is visible in A.xls even though the data is not there. Would this achieve your objective?

Comment: that's an idea indeed :) About my initial objective, may aim is to automate a sheet that is huge and ugly. So currently my chart points to these 39K lines, but I have means of having that in VB as this is actually some sort of custom array rendered in a range.

Comment: is it possible to hide a sheet and still use its data ? is it actually possible to just a sheet programmatically ?

Comment: A chart will operate off hidden data and you can access hidden data via VBA.  I have hidden data because it was secret but never because it was ugly.  Why not use a pale grey font except for the title line: "This data is not suitable for those of a nervous disposition."  Are you old enough to remember when almost every TV drama started with that line?  How can a chart's source data be in an array?

Comment: Lol, I'm 23 so maybe not ;) It's an array, simple as that (you can see curly brackets around a formula that is resulting as an array in Excel)

Comment: I will have to play with this.  Do you type in the curly backets or use Ctrl+Shift+Enter?